# Translating a description and a button inside a plugin

Tags: wordpress, translation, polylang

I have a plugin that have a text and a button. The website have four languages and I need to translate the button text and also the description.

For translation, Polylang is being used.
Inside the plugin I can't access the Polylang config.

How should I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found a solution.

I needed to prepare my plugin to receive the translation and in the end, actually was pretty simple.

This article cover everything that I needed, using PODEdit to create the PO and MO files for each language that I'm using.

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-translate-a-wordpress-plugin/

Since I was a layman in the subject, took longer to understand and figure out how to search about it.